# Is it possible to know if a WP7 application is pinned?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I thought that this code snipped :

```
var appTile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.First();

if (appTile != null)
{
    // is pinned
}
```

would tell me if my wp7 application is already pinned, but appTile is never null, even when the app isn't pinned.

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot tell if the default application Tile is actually pinned to the start, or not.

But it can be done for the secondary ones:

```
ShellTile FindTile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.NavigationUri.ToString().Contains("Page=" + PageTitle));
if (FindTile == null)
{
    // Tile has not been pinned
}
else
{
    // Tile has been pinned
}
```

Comment: It is really annoying, I wanted to only register for push tile notifications if the tile was pinned :(